# How to convert those characters not quoted to upper case?

Tags: regex, perl, shell

To format thousands of SQL queries I need to convert all the characters not in quotation mark pair to upper case.

For example:

```
select * from region where regionkey = 'America'
```

to be converted to

```
SELECT * FROM REGION WHERE REGIONKEY = 'America'
```

With perl I'm able to convert those quoted characters to upper case by:

```
perl -p -e 's/('.+?')/\U\1/g'
```

and get:

```
select * from region where regionkey = 'AMERICA'
```

The question is how to "reverse" the capture result, say, to march to not in quotation marks?

Comment: are there quotes in the quotes?  e.g. `'Hawai\'i'`?

Comment: SQL keywords are not case-sensitive. Why does it matter?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm working with a SQL engine which has all the database object names (incl. tables, views, fields) case-sensitive. I don't care it's "sELECt fROm" or "sElEcT FoRm", but REGIONKEY or RegionKey does matter. In my use case all the objects are named in upper case, to simplify the processing, I just convert everything outside the quote to upper case.

Comment: Table/Column names shouldn't be case-sensitive unless quoted. Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: @JimGarrison An in-house built one done by some students many years ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/([^']*)('[^']*'|\z)/\U$1\E$2/g
```

so

```
perl -pe's/([^'\'']*)('\''[^'\'']*'\''|\z)/\U$1\E$2/g'
```

ysth suggests a mixed-quote approach:

```
perl -pe"s/([^']*)('[^']*'|\z)/"'\U$1\E$2/g'
```

If the quotes can have backslash escapes in them, change

```
'[^']*'
```

to

```
'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on quoted substrings and uppercase every other chunk. Like this

```
my $str = "select * from region where regionkey = 'America'";

my $uc;
$str = join '', map { ($uc = !$uc) ? uc : $_ } split /('[^']*')/, $str;
print $str;
```

**output**

```
SELECT * FROM REGION WHERE REGIONKEY = 'America'
```

Comment: One-liner: `perl -pe'$_ = join "", map { ($uc^=1) ? uc : $_ } split '"/('[^']*')/"', $_'`